# sorting an array on the first number found in each element

Tags: perl, sorting

I'm looking for help sorting an array where each element is made up of "a number, then a string, then a number".  I would like to sort on the first number part of the array elements, descending (so that I list the higher numbers first), while also listing the text etc.

am still a beginner so alternatives to the below are also welcome

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = map {int( rand(49) + 1) } ( 1..100 ); # build an array of 100 random numbers between 1 and 49

my @count2;

foreach my $i (1..49) {

    my @count = join(',', @arr) =~ m/$i,/g; # maybe try to make a string only once then search trough it... ???
my $count1 = scalar(@count); # I want this $count1 to be the number of times each of the numbers($i) was found within the string/array.

    push(@count2, $count1 ." times for ". $i); # pushing a "number then text and a number / scalar, string, scalar" to an array.
}

#for (@count2) {print "$_\n";}
# try to add up all numbers in the first coloum to make sure they == 100

 #sort @count2 and print the top 7
@count2 = sort {$b <=> $a} @count2; # try to stop printout of this, or sort on =~ m/^anumber/ ??? or just on the first one or two \d

foreach my $i (0..6) {
 print $count2[$i] ."\n"; # seems to be sorted right anyway
}
```

Comment: Congrats for using `use strict` and `use warnings` as a beginner!

Comment: Please clarify what you actually want to do. You write about sorting and in the code there's something about counting. If you eventually want to count the numbers you don't need sorting ... However please provide examples for the strings you want to compute.

Comment: The count/sum was just a comment for me halo, I haven't goggled it yet... will probably ask here at SO if I can't work it out... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, store your data in an array, not in a string:

```
# inside the first loop, replace your line with the push() with this one:
push(@count2, [$count1, $i];
```

Then you can easily sort by the first element of each subarray:

```
my @sorted = sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } @count2;
```

And when you print it, construct the string:

```
printf "%d times for %d\n", $sorted[$i][0], $sorted[$i][1];
```

See also: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html, [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-an-array-by-%28anything%29?%29)

Comment: Thanks moritz, seem to be printing out. There was a typo though is:\npush(@count2, [$count1, $i]); ???

Answer (score 2):

Taking your requirements as is. You're probably better off not embedding count information in a string. However, I'll take it as a learning exercise.

Note, I am trading memory for brevity and likely speed by using a hash to do the counting.

However, the sort could be optimized by using a [Schwartzian Transform](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col64.html).

#### EDIT: Create results array using only numbers that were drawn

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @arr = map {int( rand(49) + 1) } ( 1..100 );

my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for @arr;

my @result = map sprintf('%d times for %d', $counts{$_}, $_),
             sort {$counts{$a} <=> $counts{$b}} keys %counts;

print "$_\n" for @result;
```

However, I'd probably have done something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use YAML;

my @arr;
$#arr = 99; #initialize @arr capacity to 100 elements 

my %counts;

for my $i (0 .. 99) {
    my $n = int(rand(49) + 1); # pick a number
    $arr[ $i ] = $n;           # store it
    ++$counts{ $n };           # update count
}

# sort keys according to counts, keys of %counts has only the numbers drawn
# for each number drawn, create an anonymous array ref where the first element
# is the number drawn, and the second element is the number of times it was drawn
# and put it in the @result array

my @result = map  [$_, $counts{$_}],
             sort {$counts{$a} <=> $counts{$b} }
             keys %counts;

print Dump \@result;
```

Comment: Thanks Sinan Unur, this one looks to hard for me at the moment but I'll work on it.  Am getting some repeated numbers in its output also...

Comment: Ah, I forgot to create a secondary array. Will do that.