# regex matching I think

Tags: arrays, perl, sum

First sorry if I should have added this to [my earlier question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848866/sorting-an-array-on-the-first-number-found-in-each-element), but I now have the below code and am having problems getting things to add up to 100...

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = map {int( rand(49) + 1) } ( 1..100 ); # build an array of 100 random numbers between 1 and 49

my @count2;

foreach my $i (1..49) {

my @count = join(',', @arr) =~ m/,$i,/g; #  ???
my $count1 = scalar(@count); # I want this $count1 to be the number of times each of the numbers($i) was found within the string/array.

#  push(@count2, $count1 ." times for ". $i); # pushing a "number then text and a number / scalar, string, scalar" to an array.
 push(@count2, [$count1, $i]); 
}

 #sort @count2 and print the top 7
my @sorted = sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } @count2;
my $sum = 0;
foreach my $i (0..$#sorted) {  # (0..6)

 printf "%d times for %d\n", $sorted[$i][0], $sorted[$i][1];
  $sum += $sorted[$i][0]; # try to add up/sum all numbers in the first coloum to make sure they == 100

}

print "Generated $sum random numbers.\n"; # doesn't add up to 100, I think it is because of the regex and because the first number doesn't have a "," in front of it
# seem to be always 96 or 97, 93...
```

Comment: You should explain what you're actually asking here — don't make people browse through your account profile to figure out which "earlier question" you're referring to.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the `linux` tag, you placed?

Comment: Reading the title of this question I thought you wanted this:  `/\bI think\b/` :)

Comment: @ Eknath lyer  Sorry, I got used to adding it as I'm on a linux box, and there are sometime differences...

Comment: The title is misleading. This is not a regex matching question. Please come up with a better description of your problem. It might help you better understand what you are doing as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use YAML;

my @arr;
$#arr = 99;

my %counts;

for my $i (0 .. 99) {
    my $n = int(rand(49) + 1);
    $arr[ $i ] = $n;
    ++$counts{ $n };
}

my @result = map  [$_, $counts{$_}],
             sort {$counts{$a} <=> $counts{$b} }
             keys %counts;

my $sum;
$sum += $_->[1] for @result;

print "Number of draws: $sum\n";
```

Comment: Thanks Sinan Unur... Maybe one day I'll understand, I can at least get the gist of what I am sort of doing above... will keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace these two lines:

```
my @count = join(',', @arr) =~ m/,$i,/g; #  ???
my $count1 = scalar(@count); # I want this $count1 to be the number of times each of the numbers($i) was found within the string/array.
```

with this:

```
my $count1 = grep { $i == $_ } @arr;
```

`grep` will return a list of elements where only the expression in `{}` evaluates to true. This is less error-prone and much more efficient than `join`ing the entire array and using a a regex.  Also note that `scalar` is not necessary since the variable `$count1` is scalar, so perl will return the result of `grep` in scalar context.

You can also get rid of this line:

```
push(@count2, $count1 ." times for ". $i); # pushing a "number then text and a number / scalar, string, scalar" to an array.
```

since you are already printing the same information in your last `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks very much MisterEd, this one got it working for me... will have to think about what it's doing though, as I'm still trying to figure out why - horses for courses :)
Sorry after taking another look at it, I wanted to search for and then count $i in \@count not \@arr

Answer (score 0):

You can probably reuse some well-tested code from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm).

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/ indexes /;
...
foreach my $i (1..49) {
    my @indexes = indexes { $_ == $i } @arr;
    my $count1 = scalar( @indexes );
    push( @count2, [ $count1, $i ] ); 
}
```

If you don't need the warns in the sum loop, then I'd recommend using sum from [List:Util](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/Scalar-List-Utils/lib/List/Util.pm).

```
use List::Util qw/ sum /;
...
my $sum = sum map { $_->[0] } @sorted;
```

If you insist on the loop, rewrite it as:

```
foreach my $i ( @sorted ) {
```